# How to know if there is some data to be scrolled in Quantum Grid 5?

Tags: delphi, scroll, grid, devexpress, delphi-7

I'm working in a legacy project, in Delphi 7, which uses the Express Quantum Grid 5, from DevExpress.

My grid cannot show scroll bars, so I have an external navigator to control the scrolling.

I can scroll using the `GridView.Site.ScrollContent(ADirection)` method, but I don't know how to identify if there is some data to be scrolled in any one of the four directions (Up, Down, Left and Right).

I need to know this to be able to disable the navigation buttons when no navigation is needed.

Do anybody know any solution or workaround for this problem? I could not find any method in the grid or its parts that can give me this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution...

As we bought the source code of the component, we make some changes on it when necessary.

In this case, I found a protected method named `CanScrollData(ADirection)` in the `controller` used by the gridview. All I needed to do was to make this method public and then use it.

```
Boolean canScrollLeft := Grid.ActiveView.Controller.CanScrollData(dirLeft)
```